# How to get TreeViewItems to not inherit Tooltip property from their parent

Tags: wpf, treeview, tooltip, treeviewitem

I have an application in which is a quasi IDE where a TreeView is acting as a solution explorer.  What the user is designer is a screen layout which could look like this.

```
Root
    Menus
        MainMenu
            MenuItem1
    Button Bars
        MainBar
            Button1
```

I originally had issues with context menus.  In the example above MenuItem1 doesn't have a context menu but MainMenu does.  Well, MenuItem1 would inherit the context menu from MainMenu.  I got by this by creating an empty context menu and assigning it to MenuItem1.  I'd like something more elegant though.

I have the same issues with tooltips.  If I assign one to MainMenu then MenuItem1 inherits the one assigned to MainMenu.  I tried setting the MenuItem1 tooltip to null, did nothing.  If I set it to "", an empty string it overrides the MainMenu tooltip but when you hover over MenuItem1 a small empty tooltip box appears.  I thought the system would have been smart enough to not show the box if it was an empty string but apparently not.

How can I prevent children from inheriting context menu and tooltip properties from their parents?

Updated

---

Still having issues with this.  I analyzed my items using Snoop and it indicates that these properties are inheirited, but I still don't see any solution to breaking the inheritance.

The only kludge I can think of is that for every tooltip to handle the ToolTipOpening event and inspect the string, if it has no length then jsut close it immediately.  There must be a better way though.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the exact same problem but I found a solution that works for me.  I changed the visibility of the tooltip so that it no longer appears for empty strings.

```
System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip tt = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
tt.Content = tooltipDescription;
if (tooltipDescription == null)
    tt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
item.ToolTip = tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"` this will disable your Tooltip on the desired element.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I need to do it in the code behind and I tried adding ToolTipService.SetIsEnabled(tviMyContainer, false); but it still inherited and displayed the tooltip from the parent.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I created a style with zero **Width** and **Height**:

```
<Style x:Key="NullToolTip" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

When I created **ToolTip** with this style and placed in resources:

```
<ToolTip x:Key="NoToolTip" Style="{StaticResource NullToolTip}" />
```

Then set this ToolTip for each item:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Sample" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{StaticResource NoToolTip}">
```

or in style:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource NoToolTip}" />
```

In this case, null **ToolTip** for item will be default, but when you set our **ToolTip**, it will be defined only for him.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly masking a tooltip should be done with null and not string.empty. Secondly if you had used hierarchical data template and itemssource binding for your treeview then you could have set tooltips based on your template hierachy (such as bound to a property in your object hierarchy from model or itemssource) in which case they must had taken an effect based on your specific treeview item.

As of now you can use null to mask.

Comment: When you set it to null it automatically inherits it from the parent.  The default if you don't set a tooltip is for it to be null.  I had to make it an empty string in order to get it to not inherit from the parent.  I have thought of redoing my TreeView to make proper use of binding but right now I don't have the time.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here all had issues for me so here's the approach I came up with which does avoid child tree items showing the parent item's tip.

Similar to some other answers, I use a style with a setter for the `Tooltip` property. The key differences are:

1. Binding the `Visibility` of a `ToolTip` element instead of the `TextBlock` element showing the tip.
2. Wrapping the `TextBlock` with a `Border` element. This avoided occasionally seeing a tiny, empty tip block.

```
<local:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="strToVisibilityConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="MyTreeStyleKey" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding TipText, Converter={StaticResource strToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Border>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding TipText}"/>
        </Border>
      </ToolTip>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

`StringToVisibilityConverter` is a simple converter I created which returns `Visibility.Collapsed` for null or emptry strings, `Visibility.Visible` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<[YourControl].Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="InvisibleToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
</[YourControl].Resources>
<[YourControl].ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource InvisibleToolTip}"/>
</[YourControl].ToolTip>
```

Comment: Add a description for code so that others can get an idea